# error from replacing a pandas column from a another

Tags: python, pandas

This code gives the error message :
`ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(4,5), columns =['a','b','c','d','e'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20,40).reshape(4,5), columns=['a','b','c','d','d'])
df1['a'] = df['a'].copy()
```

while the below code runs successfully.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(4,5), columns =['a','b','c','d','e'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20,40).reshape(4,5), columns=['a','b','c','d','d'])
df['a'] = df1['a'].copy()
```

I purposely makes the 2 ds in df1 columns. Can anyone explains why it is the case? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is because of duplicated columns, `d`.

You should change the column name of df1.